# How is video/audio streamed (youtube, spotify, etc.) without the data being downloadable?

Tags: video-streaming, audio-streaming, drm

Pondering this question and can't find anything on Google about it (easily). This is very much not my field, so I'm looking for a technical but simplified answer.

**How is audio/video streamed without the data being in a form that is downloadable?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't.

All of that media data is being downloaded as it's being played back.  This data can easily be saved, with basic proxy tools, browser extensions, custom scripts, etc.

At best, the media can be encrypted with a DRM system.  This prevents directly copying playable media data at the network level, but of course the media must be decrypted for playback.  And, after it's been decrypted, it's subject to being re-recorded.

Comment: “This prevents directly copying the media data at the network level” is false. DRMd content is still downloadable from the network. But is is encrypted, so it can not be played without a key.

Comment: @szatmary Yes, agreed, that's what I was getting with the second half of that sentence.  I'll clarify, thanks.

Comment: but you still say “at the network level”. Modern DRM works offline. No network necessary. Often (but not always) the key if download from the network but it could also just be a part of the application. The playback is blocked at the content decryption module, which runs in the client.

Comment: @szatmary Yes, I don't disagree with you.  I'm simply trying to say that if no DRM is in use, the content is in-the-clear and can be easily accessed even as it's being played back.  But if DRM is in use and the content is encrypted, the extra step of decryption must occur.  Feel free to write a better-phrased answer if you have something in mind... I'd be happy to up-vote it.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that the sentence `This prevents directly copying playable media data at the network level` is incorrect. There is nothing at the network level that prevents copying data, playable or unplayable. So somebody reading this answer could walk away with a misunderstanding of how DRM works. I'll just leave it at that.